# How do I send subviews to front programmatically? (have tried bringSubview to front)

Tags: swift, image, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

In my `UICollectionViewCell` I have an image and a label. The picture takes up the whole cell (which I want) - however, the label is placed behind the image, so it's not visible. I have tried `bringSubview(toFront: titleLabel)`, but nothing happens... I got no clue what to do really, have done a lot of searching.

This is the code for the cell, I don't use Storyboard as you can see (sorry for messy constraints, was testing different solutions to find out if this was the problem)

```
import UIKit

class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        setupBasket()

    }

    func setupViews() {

    }

    func setupBasket(){

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

class VideoCell: BaseCell {

    var selectedItemID : String!
    static let sharedInstance = VideoCell()
    var video: Video? {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.text = video?.title
            setupThumbnailImage()

        }
    }


    func setupThumbnailImage() {
        if let thumbnailImageUrl = video?.thumbnail_image_name {
            thumbnailImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString(thumbnailImageUrl)
        }
    }

    let thumbnailImageView: CustomImageView = {
        let imageView = CustomImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "taylor_swift_blank_space")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let textView = UILabel()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.text = "Clothes"
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        return textView
    }()


    let separatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 230/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1)
        return view
    }()

    var titleLabelHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    let addtoBasket = UIButton(type: .contactAdd)


    override func setupViews() {

        addtoBasket.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 20, height: 60)

        addSubview(addtoBasket)
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
        addSubview(separatorView)
        addSubview(addtoBasket)


        titleLabel.superview!.bringSubview(toFront: titleLabel)


        //horizontal constraints
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-0-[v0]-0-|", views: thumbnailImageView)


        //vertical constraints
        addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-1-[v0]-1-|", views: thumbnailImageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-0-[v0]-1-|", views: separatorView)


        addtoBasket.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addtoBasket.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        addtoBasket.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        addtoBasket.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addtoBasket.superview!.centerXAnchor, constant: 90).isActive = true
        addtoBasket.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addtoBasket.superview!.centerYAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true

        //top constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))

        //right constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        //right constraint
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))

        //height constraint
        titleLabelHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)
        addConstraint(titleLabelHeightConstraint!)

    }
}
```

Comment: Your constraints are probably wrong.  Add one view at a time and check that each one is correct.

Comment: @LouFranco I have made the image smaller and can clearly see that the text is under, so it shouldn't be the constraints. The button 'addtoBasket' constraints works and is not under the image. I have also tried tried all constraints practices for the label but nothing works, but maybe there is still something conflicting.. really strange

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the labels layer and set its zPosition.

Try `titleLabel.layer.zPosition = 1`

Answer (score 1):

There was clearly something wrong with the constraints, now working! Thanks